# Access VBA Library load Subform doesn't come form library

Tags: ms-access, vba

I built a Library MS Access with a number of standard features and forms, including an iGrid control for listviews.

The mainform for the list view is loaded and controlled from the Library file but I cannot load a subform that does not come from the library? I tried several things but nothing seems to work.

I do not know if it is not possible or I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for you help.

Code:

```
If ControlExists("sub_right_sidebar") = True Then
        With g_form.Controls("sub_right_sidebar")
            If rightsidebar & "" <> "" Then
                    .SourceObject = "frm_example_form_name"
                    Dim c As Single
                    c = .Form.Width
                    .Move Left:=CmToTwips(ResX) - c, Top:=sngTop, Width:=c, Height:=sngHeight
                    .Visible = True
            Else
                .Visible = False
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

But the formname "frm_example_form_name" is not in the same file as the code. This code is in a access file (I name it library) and this library is loaded into another access file by references.

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I post some code in the original question.